# el bucle no continua en python

Tags: python, bucles, while

Estoy haciendo un juego de carrera de caballos con python básico, donde hay dos jugadores que deben llegar a la cantidad de 100 pts para ganar la carrera, lo que pasa es que el codigo que tira numeros al azar se ejecuta una sola vez, me pueden ayudar?

Codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto, de este modo será más fácil para otros usuarios el poder ayudarte. También te invito a realizar el [tour] y de paso te ganas tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges).

Comment: Evita utilizar imágenes ya que no todos pueden verlas, agrega tu código con el formato correspondiente para que algún colaborador pueda replicarlo y ayudarte mejor, veo que eres nuevo, date una vuelta por el [tour] y así comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y en [ask].

Comment: Hay una mala lógica. Defines `types = ["Basto", "Sword", ...]`. Y dentro del `while` indicas `types = random.choice(types)`. La primera vez, con algo de suerte, el valor aleatorio de `types` coincidirá con el de `player_one` o `player_two` e imprimirá que avanzó `X` pasos. En la siguiente iteración `types` no es una lista, si no una cadena, por ejemplo `"Sword"` así que en `random.choice("Sword")`, tendrás una letra (ejemplo, `w`), y eso no coincidirá nunca más con el valor de los `player_xxx`, por lo que entrará en un ciclo infinito. Si pones el código como texto se te podría ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 3):

Hay varios problemas. El más serio es que reemplazas `types`, que originalmente es una lista, con el resultado de `random.choice()`, que es un string en este caso. Debes usar otra variable para conservar la lista original.

También te falta un `else:` en el caso de que la carta de ambos jugadores coincida.

El otro problema es dentro del ciclo no vuelves a pedir las cartas.

Este sería tu código con las correcciones incorporadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]